# How do I recreate this photo cut out effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

[image: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-8MJ7YDdSs_A/UHAFTOEgKZI/AAAAAAAAQLA/a62uGwuIk_U/s1600/k3.jpg]

The above is the wanted effect, Please help me out!

Comment: Things you need to know to do this: 1. How to make image black and white 2. How to make polygonal selections and perhaps how to invert selection 3. How to scale layers 4. How to rotate layers

Comment: ...and how to scale layers. Basically learn about layers  :)

Answer (score 2):

Right click the image layer in the layers panel, and choose Duplicate Layer or use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (Mac). Make the new layer Black and White by clicking `Image` > `Adjustments` > `Black and White`. You might also wish to decrease the Brightness/Contrast a little - it's in the same `Adjustments` section of the menu.

Make polygonal selections of the black and white image with the Polygonal Lasso tool, then Copy and Paste these selections as new layers. Hide the black and white layer by clicking the eye icon in the layers panel.

Next, rescale the various polygonal shapes just a little by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to transform them. Use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> if you are using Mac.

[image: Screenshot showing layers]

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it like this...

1. Open your image or use existing psd comp.
2. Duplicate your layer that you wish to apply this polygon shatter effect to
3. On the duplicated layer, apply the black and white effect you desire using either of these methods...
   **3.1** `top menu > image > adjustments > black and white`
   **3.2** `top menu > image > adjustments > hue and saturation` (take saturation right down to kill the color then adjust the `levels` to enhance the light and darks
   **3.3**. `top menu > image > adjustments > gradient map` (set the gradient colors to be black and white)
4. Now you have a duplicated **Layer 1 copy** layer with the black and white style you desire... [image]
5. Still on **Layer 1 copy** go to `top menu > layer > vector mask > hide all`... [image]
6. Now select the `Pen Tool` from the tools menu [image]
7. And click the `Pen Tool` on the vector mask to create points, which you can then begin to draw polygon or triangle shapes...[image]
8. Now hit `command (or ctrl) + T` or go `top menu > edit > free transform` [image]
9. Now you can move or drag **Layer 1 copy** around and also subtly increase or decrease the size by dragging the corners whilst holding `shift` key then hitting `enter` to finish [image]
10. And then duplicate this layer (right click on layer), and delete the layer mask by right clicking on the mask

    [image]
11. Then repeat the process from **Step 5**